# Trouble in understanding question related to the work, energy and power chapter about pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, work, power

Two pendulums of masses $m_1$ and $m_2$ ($m_1>m_2$) and strings of same length are taken. The densities of the both the bobs are the same ($d_1=d_2$), if we compare the time period of the two pendulums then:

(A) $T_1>T_2$

(B) $T_1=T_2$

(C) $T_1<T_2$

(D) Can't say

Comment: What's the formula for the time period of a simple pendulum?

Comment: What's your question about the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The well-known formula for the period of a simple pendulum performing small oscillations doesn't involve the mass of the bob (because the gravitational force is in the ratio $m_1/m_2$, but so too is the inertia.) However for a real pendulum there are at least three small mass-dependent effects, owing to the bob of larger mass having a larger volume ...

(a) Where is the string attached to the bob? If it is to a point on the surface of the bob, then the centre of bob 1 will be further away from the string support than the centre of bob 2, because bob 1 is larger. Therefore $T_1>T_2$.

(b) But perhaps 'string length' should be taken to mean distance, $l$, from string support to centre of bob. This does not render the bob size totally irrelevant, because we still don't have a simple pendulum, that is a point mass on a light inextensible string or rod. The finite size of the bob means that its moment of inertia about the point of support is $m \left(l^2 + \frac25 a^2\right)$ in which $a$ is the radius of a spherical bob. So
$$\frac {T_1}{T_2} =\sqrt{\frac{\left(l^2 + \frac25 a_1^2\right)}{\left(l^2 + \frac25 a_2^2\right)}}\approx 1 +\frac{a_1^2-a_2^2}{5 l^2}$$

So we still have $T_1>T_2$, even though the effect will be very small.

(c) And then there is the increased air resistance on the larger bob (for a given speed). This increases the damping and slightly increases the period. So, yet again, $T_1>T_2$.

Comment: Apologia: This may be a homework-type question, but it's not without general interest, and my answer still leaves A, B and D as possible 'correct' answers to the multiple choice question', since I don't know what effects the student is supposed to ignore!